# How to build same browser response for all types of files with laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, browser

**Goal:** When client requests to see a file from server, i want the client's browser to ask what to do (open or download file). How can i build that?

So far i have methods like those:

```
public static function getFileContent($fullpath){
   //yes, i can get both file and its extension
   $file = File::get($fullpath);
   $mimeType = File::extension($fullpath);
   $response = Response::make($file, 200, array('content-type'=>$mimeType));
   return $response;
}
```

and the other method calls the above

```
$path = $instance->the_file_path_on_the_database;
return MyClass::getFileContent($path);
```

In **this** case, if the uploaded file is PDF, png, jpeg etc. browser automatically opens the file, which is okay.

But when it comes to the *.xlsx or *.docx, browser asks me what to do but the file name isn't as the same as what i have stored on the database and it has no extension. Also the file is automatically renamed as the route's name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads)

> The download method may be used to generate a response that forces the
>   user's browser to download the file at the given path. The download
>   method accepts a file name as the second argument to the method, which
>   will determine the file name that is seen by the user downloading the
>   file. Finally, you may pass an array of HTTP headers as the third
>   argument to the method:
>
> `return response()->download($pathToFile);`
>
> `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

Comment: Thanks, but i was seeking to implement something like where browser-supported files will be opened automatically, the others is being asked what to do. I suppose i have to create my own cases, but thanks for the answer anyways.